# Find all values of x,y that solve a*x + b*y = c

Tags: math

I'm stuck in an exercise where I need to find all the values available to solve the equation

> **a*x + b*y = c**

**Range: x >= -32768 , y <= 32767**

**Input:** `a,b,c`.

**Output:** Values of `x,y` that solve the equation, otherwise `zero`.

I'm trying to create an algorithm which solves this, but no luck at the moment. Any help is  highly appreciated.

Comment: How about loop? And checking all possible options?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/). As a hint however, this appears closely related to the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: @BrettHale Is there an ASM code which computes it using the ext. euc. algorithm?

Comment: Step 1: Solve the equation for y (which can be done symbolically), Step 2: Write code that loops through all available values of `x` and solves for `y` using the solution found in step 1.

Comment: I suggest reading the EEA first. There may be no solutions, or infinite (x, y) pairs of solutions, or (provably) 2 solution pairs of (x, y) s.t. `|x| + |y|` is minimal. Consider a working C implementation first. Compile (without optimization) to have a good look at what the assembly is doing, and go from there. If nothing else, you have a C program to perform a 'sanity' check on the ASM output:)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So first I find `y` in `by = c`, then I loop from x =  -32768 to `0`, and find all the `x` that solve with the found `y`? and what if I can't find an integer `y`, and it becomes float? do I need to take the quotient and refrain from the remainder if `y` is found as float in `by=c`?

Comment: No, you *solve* the equation for y, which will be this: `y=(c-a*x)/b`. Here you can plug in a value for `x` and calculate `y`. And yes, this may produce a floating point value.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I see, about `x`, I loop it from -32768 till zero? If yes, how will it be in hex? FFFF till 0000?

Comment: I found an algorithm. loop in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's 2 ways to solve this

first one:

```
iterate all (x) from -32768 to 32768
  iterate all (y) from -32768 to 32768
    check if a*x + b*y  == c
```

which doesn't make that much sense, for y is dependant on x

```
a*x + b*y = c
      b*y = c-a*x
        y =(c-a*x)/b
```

so this algorithm is a lot faster:

```
iterate all (x) from -32768 to 32768
    calculate y as (c-a*x)/b
    check if a*x + b*y  == c
```

Comment: There is no DOS, Assembly or x86 in the question, nor in the answer. This should indeed be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I appreciate the reduction of time complexity from O(n^2) to O(n). But because the question was tagged with `x86`, `assembly` and `dos`, you should implement an assembly 16-bit Real-Mode version of this algorithm, probably making use of AX:DX registers.

Comment: @tommy thank you. I will implement this the second way